# Getting Bluetooth to Work using Asus BT211 with Dell Inspiron E1505

Tags: 12.10, dell, bluetooth, asus, inspiron

I'm using an Asus BT211 USB bluetooth adapter on my Dell Inspiron E1505 and I cannot seem to get it running.  I've tried many different searches and turned up nothing, at least not for modern versions of Ubuntu.  I'm not sure what further information I should post, so please let me know and I'll post it.

I've tried using Ubuntu's bluetooth manager and I've tried using Blueman, neither seem to do the trick.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as this line is often used to restart many services:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/servicename restart
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```